How to protect swagger/1.0/swagger.json route in .NET 8?
I have created a custom SwaggerUI (index.html) file in a ReactJS app, which is accessible at myapplication.com/docs/swagger/index.html. Since the route goes through /docs/, STS authentication is applied. However, the SwaggerUI fetches data from the /swagger/v1/swagger.json endpoint, which is currently unprotected, allowing anyone to access it at myapplication.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json. How can I secure this endpoint in .NET 8?
ReactJS:
App.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-react'
import 'swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css'
import { GettingStartedSection } from 'sections/getting-started'

const App = () => {
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState<string | undefined>('getting-started')
    
    return (
        <CustomPageWrapper>
            <div id="App" className="App">                

                <DocumentationWrapper>
                    <GettingStartedSection />
                    <SwaggerUI layout="BaseLayout" url="/v1/swagger/1.0/swagger.json" />
                    <HandlingErrorsAndVersioningSection />
                </DocumentationWrapper>
            </div>
        </CustomPageWrapper>
    )
}

export default App

root-app.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContextProvider } from './contexts/auth.context'
import { AuthzContextProvider } from './contexts/authz.context'
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/user'
import { AuthCallbackPage, LogoutCallbackPage, LogoutPage, SilentRenewPage } from './pages/auth'
import { AuthorizedRoute } from './routes/authorized-route'
import App from './App'

const RootApp = () => {
    const returnEmptyComponent = () => <></>

    return (
        <AuthContextProvider>
            <AuthzContextProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <UserContextProvider>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/docs/auth/callback" component={AuthCallbackPage} />
                            <Route path="/docs/auth/silent-renew" component={SilentRenewPage} />
                            <Route exact path="/account/logout" component={LogoutPage} />
                            <Route exact path="/docs/auth/logout/callback" component={LogoutCallbackPage} />                            
                            <AuthorizedRoute path="/*" component={App} />
                        </Switch>
                    </UserContextProvider>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </AuthzContextProvider>
        </AuthContextProvider>
    )
}

export default RootApp

C# code:
app.UseSwagger();

 app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
 {
     // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
     bool isPathPrefixDefined = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(swaggerOptions?.PathPrefix);

     if (isPathPrefixDefined)
     {
         foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
         {
             options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerOptions.PathPrefix}/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                 $"{swaggerOptions.GeneratedJsonName}  {description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()}");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
         {
             options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
         }
     }

     if (swaggerOptions.IncludeAuthentication)
     {
         options.OAuthClientId(swaggerOptions.SecurityDefinition.ClientId);
         options.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerOptions.SecurityDefinition.ClientSecret);
     }
 });


What's the problem with having the API documentation (not the API) public?

We don’t want to make the API documentation publicly accessible . Users should only be able to access the API documentation if their authentication has been verified.

What library are you using for the docs? At least with NSwag the path for the JSON docs can be modified.

We are using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Have you checked the documentation? You can use app.MapSwagger().RequireAuthorization(); out of the box. Please post the code that configures Swagger in your project and changes the route to docs

@Panagiotis Kanavos, Yes I tried app.MapSwagger().RequireAuthorization(); but still i am able to load swagger.json which is showing all the endpoints details.

Docu looks a bit unclear to me on this as it says "Swagger UI" that would be the html to me and not the json file shown in the UI. At the same it it shows a curl command that get the json and they also call that Swagger UI. OpenAPI/Swagger makes a clear distinction between the UI and the actual OpenAPI description shown in the UI. The documentation does not :(

We are using swagger-ui-react component link.
ReactJS code:
DocumentationWrapper>                     <GettingStartedSection />                     <SwaggerUI layout="BaseLayout" url={env.REACT_APP_SWAGGER_JSON_URL} />                     <HandlingErrorsAndVersioningSection />                 </DocumentationWrapper>

One way, accordignly to the docs, you could use
app.MapSwagger().RequireAuthorization();

Alternative option, if that's not enough, is to implement something like authorization middleware. Sample implementation:
public class AuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var path = context.Request.Path;

        // You can pick your own logic to decide if each swagger
        // request should be protected or not.
        if (path.Value.Contains("swagger"))
        {
            // Basic auth check, you would need most probably something more :)
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return;
            }
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
        await _next(context);
    }
}

and the use it in your app with
app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();


That's what RequiresAuthoerization() does already. The ASP.NET Core OpenAPI docs show how to require authorization with app.MapSwagger().RequireAuthorization();

@PanagiotisKanavos I used it in my sample app, and it did not fully worked. But sure, good point to include in answer. Thanks!
